# Flutter App not running in my oneplus 7 even its showing connected, everything is done related to developer option

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, adb

[this image is proof of my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYCV4.png)

```
$ flutter device
1 connected device:

GM1901 • bf9d2d80 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)


$ flutter run
Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components.
```

this error keeps coming, but when I run `flutter doctor` or `flutter devices` it shows connected.

```
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.34.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.1.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • GM1901 • bf9d2d80 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn6H1.png)

Comment: Is it working with a normal project in AS rather than a flutter one?

Comment: I did not try that I'm using VS code and not Android studio this is my first project.

Comment: Are "Developer Options" and "USB Debbugging" switched to 'on' on your device ?

Comment: yes both are enabled. @Muldec

Comment: can you add the result of `flutter doctor -v` to your question ?

Comment: I did and it is showing the result is- `[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.34.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.1.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • GM1901 • bf9d2d80 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Alok Rawat@UCLP1631 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/pincodeapp
$`@Muldec

Comment: Show your `adb devices` command ouptut

Comment: is this all `flutter doctor -v` shows ? It's missing a `Flutter` and an `Android Toolchain` entry

Comment: @Muldec  I have attached a picture see this please-  [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYCV4.png)

Comment: Thx for the picture, I had no doubt you have the error you describe. I'm just pointing that the result of `flutter doctor -v` you've posted seems incomplete. There should be more information in the console when running this command.

Comment: @Muldec agreed to you. since I'm very new to this so don't know exactly what error is this.

Comment: Did you tried the following command:  
`flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk`?

Comment: And this: `flutter doctor --android-licenses`?

Comment: `Alok Rawat@UCLP1631 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/flutter_calculator-master
$ flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk
Setting "android-sdk" value to "C:/Users/UC/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/path/to/android/sdk".

Alok Rawat@UCLP1631 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/flutter_calculator-master
$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Unable to locate Android SDK.

Alok Rawat@UCLP1631 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/flutter_calculator-master
$` @RobertoManfreda

Comment: it says `Unable to locate Android SDK.`

Comment: oh no, you need to change `path/to/sdk` with the path of your sdk installation folder!!!!!!!!!!!!!! i don't think your sdk is in `C:/Users/UC/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/path/to/android/sdk` !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: here is my SDK located **C:\Program Files\platform-tools** now what will be the command to locate the SDK. @RobertoManfreda

Comment: Download pda.net+ and install "http://pdanet.co/a/"

Comment: @VithaniRavi No!! I'm a flutter guy... not interested in your pda.net+ thing.

Comment: @AlokRawat pda.net+ is softwere it can use for run app using android studio

Comment: I had an issue where the flutter app would work on all the devices except Oneplus. It started working when I disabled RAM boost in the settings. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really answer why this is happening, but if you just press `F5` to run from VS Code (instead of using the terminal) it may work (or at least give a better error), as VS Code is showing your device in the status bar, and we explicitly pass the devices ID to Flutter when launching projects in VS Code.

If you launch from the terminal as shown in your screenshot, you'll miss out on a lot of functionality like hot-reload-on-save, lots of debug toggles, Dart DevTools and of course the debugger :-)